# while working in custom owl carousel, my carousel is not showing in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

```
function themestyle(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mainstyle', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'boostrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.min.css' ); 

    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.carousel.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.theme.default.min.css' );
   
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-style-theme', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script('owl-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/owl.carousel.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/abc.js');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themestyle' );
```

Comment: The console is your friend. You should be able to spot what is not "working" by checking the console.

Answer (score 0):

There is some parameter is missing in wp_enqueue_script. I fixed it. Please check below. Hopefully working on it.

```
function themestyle(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mainstyle', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'boostrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.min.css' ); 

    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.carousel.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.theme.default.min.css' );
   
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), time(), true );
    wp_enqueue_script('owl-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/owl.carousel.min.js', array('jquery'), time(), true );
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/abc.js', array('jquery'), time(), true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themestyle' );
```